# How do you reassess $_REQUEST?

Tags: php, get

I need to assign a value to a `$_GET` variable, however all my values are accessed through `$_REQUEST`. Is there a way to reevaluate `$_REQUEST` after I've assigned my `$_GET` variable?

Comment: You shouldn't sniff and manipulate super-globals. This sounds like an X-Y problem.

Comment: Don't assign values to `$_GET`.  This is poor practice.  How will you know what data came in on the query string, vs. what you assigned?

Comment: I need to make all $_get values lower cased and I don't want to create yet another variable to do the job. Then if the variable is blank, I need it to have the value "all"

Comment: @KI4JGT but why do they have to be inside the `$_GET` superglobal? It is much better practice to assign them to a completely separate array...

Comment: I like things simple. It just seems a major waste of time to assign yet another value when what I need to manipulate is already available. IDK. Thanks though guys. I guess I'll just have to make another value.

Answer (score 2):

No. The PHP GET/POST/REQUEST superglobals are built/populated **ONCE** during the script's startup/parsing phase. Once that is done, they are never touched again, so

```
$_GET['foo'] = 'foo';
$_REQUEST['foo'] = 'bar';
echo $_GET['foo'];
```

will output `foo`, not `bar`. This is also why doing a `setcookie()` will not be reflected in $_COOKIE until the NEXT script execution.

Generally speaking, you should **NOT** be changing values in the _GET/_POST/_REQUEST superglobals. Treat them as read-only.